# Ember Data routing/mapping to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, json, ember.js, routes, ember-data

I've been struggling to understand this concept, and I've put a LOT of time into researching  this but I'm getting absolutely nowhere.

I have a MYSQL database at a cheap host (one.com). I've made a table in said database, and now I want my Ember app to fetch all entries from it.

How do I accomplish this? As I understand it, ember-data tries to fetch information from the specific item URL.. but how do I map my database entries with corresponding URLs?

I can't install any software on the server directly as I do not own it. There is support for PHP though. Using PHP I can easily retrieve all database entries and encode them to JSON with the correct formatting requested by ember-data, but I have no idea on what to do next.

## **www.myurl.com/blog/js/app.js**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

// data storage -----------------------------------------------------

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
        adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
            url: 'http://www.myurl.com/blog'
        })

});

// routers, routes --------------------------------------------------

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('contact');
    this.resource('items', { path: "/items/" });
    this.resource('item', { path: "/items/:item_id"});
    this.resource('hearts');
    this.resource('tags');
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function() {
        this.transitionTo('items');
    }
});

App.ItemsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.Item.find();
    }
});

App.ItemRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return App.Item.find(params.item_id);
    }
});

// controllers --------------------------------------------------------

App.ItemsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    // ...
});

App.ItemController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    // ...
});

// model -----------------------------------------------------------

App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
    tag: DS.attr('string'),
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    posted: DS.attr('date'),
    updated: DS.attr('date'),
    intro: DS.attr('string'),
    full: DS.attr('string'),
    visible: DS.attr('number')
});
```

## **www.myurl.com/blog/items/index.php**

```
$host = "myhost";
$usr = "myuser";
$pwd = "mypwd";
$db= "mydb";

$connect = mysql_connect("$host", "$usr", "$pwd", "$db") or die("errormsg");

mysql_select_db("$db", $connect) or die("errormsg");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

$rows = array();

if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $rows['post'][]=$row;
    }
}

print(json_encode($rows));

mysql_close($db);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you are most of the way there, next step is to give it a try and do some debugging.

Step one: make sure your API is returning JSON the way ember expects. Try something like this from javascript console:

```
$.getJSON("/items").then( function(response) {
  console.log("response: ", response);
});
```

Response should be list of items. Is it?

Step two: See if ember-data is able to fetch items using the api. So from console, try:

```
App.Item.find({}).then( function(items) {
  console.log("item count: ", items.get('length'));
  console.log("items: ", items.getEach('id'));
});
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your post! Step one works correctly whereas Step 2 does not. How do I tell Ember to load all it's items from a specific URL? I have tried using DS.RESTAdapter.create({ url : 'http://www.myurl.com' }) and then setting the path of 'items' in App.Router.map to '/items' but it does not recieve any data.

Comment: Ember does not use the path from App.Router to determine the url your API. It expects API to follow restful conventions as explained here: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_url-conventions - you can see what url ember is trying to use by opening chrome browser tools and looking for external requests when you call App.Item.find({}), then make sure your api is setup to respond to the correct url.

Comment: Ah, that explains a lot, I think I understand how to make it work now. Thanks! I will update my OP with a working PHP API solution once it's done.

Comment: Cool glad that made sense. So does this answer your question or do you need more help?